# React Component vs Element for reusability in the same file

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Within the same file, I'm having an element (or group of elements) that I want to convert to something *reusable*. But because it is very small, I don't want to create a new file.

Ex.

```
// Article.js

const Article = props => {
  const { name, tel } = props

  return (
    <div>
      <section>
        <p>Content A</p>
        <small>Contact {name} now, via {tel}</small>
      </section>
      <small>Contact {name} now, via {tel}</small>
      <div>
        Having questions?
        <small>Contact {name} now, via {tel}</small>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

As you can see here, `<small>Contact {name} now, via {tel}</small>` is being used many times in `Article` component. So I want to convert it to something reusable, either a Component or just a JSX element.

The **key points** are:

1. I **do not** want to create a new file, because it will never being used by other components.
2. It needs to display content depending on `name` and `tel` variables.
3. It **does not** need to be flexible, the `name` and `tel` will always be the same as from `Article` props.

So I tried to achieve my goal with:

**Option 1:** Separated React Component (in the same file)

```
// Article.js

const Contact = props => {
  const { name, tel } = props
  return <small>Contact {name} now, via {tel}</small>
}

const Article = props => {
  const { name, tel } = props

  return (
    <div>
      <section>
        <p>Content A</p>
        <Contact name={name} tel={tel}/>
      </section>
      <Contact name={name} tel={tel}/>
      <div>
        Having questions?
        <Contact name={name} tel={tel}/>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

But from my **key point number 3**, I find this option redundant because I have no need to make `Contact` accepting `props`. Since this component will always display the same `name` and `tel` as from `Article`. So I come up with Option 2.

**Option 2**: React Component in React Component

```
// Article.js

const Article = props => {
  const { name, tel } = props

  const Contact = () => (
    <small>Contact {name} now, via {tel}</small>
  )

  return (
    <div>
      <section>
        <p>Content A</p>
        <Contact />
      </section>
      <Contact />
      <div>
        Having questions?
        <Contact />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

The `Contact` component is shorter because it accepts no `props`. But the question is if it does not accepting props, shouldn't I just write it as a JSX element? So I come up with Option 3.

**Option 3**: JSX Element in React Component

```
// Article.js

const Article = props => {
  const { name, tel } = props

  const renderContact = <small>Contact {name} now, via {tel}</small>

  return (
    <div>
      <section>
        <p>Content A</p>
        {renderContact}
      </section>
      {renderContact}
      <div>
        Having questions?
        {renderContact}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

This one I don't know how to name it properly (`renderContact`, `contactElement`, or `contact`?) because I have not seen it much.

Every option is working, but I want to know the differences between these styles,

1. Performance - how does each one work / how does it affect the perf?
2. Pros and Cons
3. Limitations - is there anything to worry when using it?
4. Popularities - what is the standard way of writing React?

Answer (score 0):

In this situation we write a reusable function usually called renderer

```
const Article = props => {
   const { name, tel } = props

   const renderer=(name,tel)=>{
           return (
               <small>Contact {name} now, via {tel}</small>
           )   
        }
  return (
    <div>
      <section>
        <p>Content A</p>
        {renderer(name,tel)}
      </section>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```